# error navigating to URL with watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, cucumber, watir-webdriver

Using IE8 and Windows 7

I have the following ruby code:

```
new_browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie
my_url = "http://myworkingurl.mydomain.net/mypage.html"
new_browser.goto my_url
```

When the Internet Explorer window opens, I get the following modal popup:

```
A program on your computer has corrupted your default search provider
setting for Internet Explorer.

Internet Explorer has reset this setting to your original search provider,
<redacted>.

Internet Explorer will now open Search Settings, where you can change this
setting or install more search providers.
```

Because of this unexpected modal popup, the following exception gets thrown:

```
Failed to navigate to http://myworkingurl.mydomain.net/mypage.html. This usually means that a call to the COM method IWebBrowser2::Navigate2() failed.
```

I can close the modal window and it will start working, but then a few minutes later the same issue will occur. How can I permanently fix this issue?

Comment: What happens if you open that url in IE without using watir-webdriver (or any automation)?

Comment: It works if I do it manually. I only get the dialog when running cucumber, and I get the dialog every single time, regardless of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a [hotfix from Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2171141). Try that.

Comment: I really wish that worked. However none of the hotfixes will install! It says it's not applicable for my computer but i know it is.